# Maya C++ API equivalent of MEL setKeyframe

Tags: c++, maya, mel, maya-api

Is there an equivalent of the MEL `setKeyframe` command in the Maya C++ API? It seems to exist for python (`maya.cmds.setKeyframe`) but I grepped the C++ include directory and didn't find anything relevant. Nor have I found any hints in the SDK documentation.

Comment: Check here http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2016/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m_fn_anim_curve_html

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574938/maya-duplicate-animcurve-in-the-api-c)

Comment: No the scripting api and the extension api are not equivalent. They have different purposes. You MAY want to read [this](http://www.creativecrash.com/forums/api/topics/new-to-the-api-then-read-this-33) before you go any further. Its old but still as relevant today as it was then.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried MFnAnimCurve class ?, it has functions like addKey and addKeyframe() http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2016/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m_fn_anim_curve_html and http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2016/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m_fn_anim_curve_html which will be the one you looking for I think and ..  there is a python example in python maya group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python_inside_maya/0QIopdTL5G0.. Hope that helps